# Color points with the color as a column in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe where a color is given for each point in a column:

```
d<-data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10,col=c(rep("red",n=5),rep("green",n=5)))
d$col<-as.character(d$col)
ggplot(data=d,aes(x=x,y=y,colour=col))+geom_point()
```

As you can see, the colour is not interpreted as a colour, but a group,

[image]

can ggplot handle such cases?

Comment: @DavidHeckmann I don't believe this is a good dupe target. It deals with a consistent coloring for groups across a number of separate plots. However, I believe the actual question has been asked before.

Answer (score 23):

This question has probably been asked and answered before. However, there is another issue in setting up the data.

The OP is creating the data by

```
d <- data.frame(x = 1:10,
                y = 1:10,
                col = c(rep("red", n = 5), rep("green", n = 5)))
```

This results in an alternation of the two colours

```
d
#    x  y   col
#1   1  1   red
#2   2  2 green
#3   3  3   red
#4   4  4 green
#5   5  5   red
#6   6  6 green
#7   7  7   red
#8   8  8 green
#9   9  9   red
#10 10 10 green
```

Reason is that `n` is not a defined parameter to the `rep()` function. According to `?rep`, valid parameters are `times`, `lenght.out`, and `each`.

Probably, the OP has meant

```
d <- data.frame(x = 1:10,
                y = 1:10,
                col = c(rep("red", 5), rep("green", 5)))
```

which results in successive rows being coloured in the same colour:

```
d
#    x  y   col
#1   1  1   red
#2   2  2   red
#3   3  3   red
#4   4  4   red
#5   5  5   red
#6   6  6 green
#7   7  7 green
#8   8  8 green
#9   9  9 green
#10 10 10 green
```

By the way,

```
col = c(rep("red", 5), rep("green", 5))
```

can be written more clearly as

```
col = rep(c("red", "green"), each = 5)
```

---

With this, the following plot statements

```
library(ggplot2)
# variant 1 (OP's own answer)
ggplot(data = d, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point(colour = d$col)
# variant 2 (aosmith' comment, more "ggplot2-like")
ggplot(data = d, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = col)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_colour_identity()
```

produce the same chart:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Just found out how:

color should be given as a separate vector, and not related to the data

```
ggplot(data=d,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point(colour=d$col)
```

Comment: Also see `scale_color_identity`