# create bar plot in ggplot2 and add dots according to labels from another data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
df1 <- data.frame(var=c("foo","bar","baz"), value=c(10,20,30))
df2 <- data.frame(var1=c("foo","foo","bar","baz"),var2=c("bar","baz","foo","foo"), value=c(23,18,26,33), color=c("blue","green","red","yellow"))

p <- ggplot(aes(x=var, y=value), data=df1) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Now I would like to add a dot to each bar of `p` according to the labels in `df2$var1` and `df2$var2` with the color specified in `df2$color`. 
For example, showing a `blue` dot over the bars `foo` and `bar` with a value of `23`. 
A `green` dot over the bars `foo` and `baz` with a value of `18`, and so on.

I'm not sure how to implement this in ggplot2...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Color points with the color as a column in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43129280/color-points-with-the-color-as-a-column-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the colour of `geom_point` by using `colour` outside of the `aes`. With your example, you can do something like that:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(aes(x=var, y=value), data=df1) + geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_point(data = df2, aes(x = var1, y= value), colour = df2$color)+
  geom_point(data = df2, aes(x = var2, y= value), colour = df2$color)
```

**EDIT: Use of scale_color_identity**

The solution above will work in your simple case. However, if you need to do faceting for example, it will be better to use the option  `scale_color_identity`as proposed by @MrFlick.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(aes(x=var, y=value), data=df1) + geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_point(data = df2, aes(x = var1, y= value, color = color))+
  geom_point(data = df2, aes(x = var2, y= value, color = color))+
  scale_color_identity()
```

[image]

Comment: @MrFlick, you're totally right, I did'nt know about this option `scale_color_identity)`. I will correct my answer