# color of arcs in ggraph based on column value, number of request values

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggraph

This question is about the ggraph library in R. This is the working example

```
set.seed(3)
widths <- sample(seq(0.1,1,0.1), 10)
test.df <- data.frame("from" = seq(1,10), 
                      "to" = rep(c(2,6),5), 
                      "col" = rgb(seq(0,1, length.out=10),0,0), 
                      "width" = factor(widths, levels=sort(widths)))

arc_test <- graph_from_data_frame(test.df)

ggraph(arc_test, layout = 'linear', circular = TRUE) + 
  geom_edge_arc0(aes(edge_width=width, edge_color=col)) + 
  scale_color_identity() +
  coord_fixed() +
  geom_node_text(label=test.df$from)

> test.df
   from to     col width
1     1  2 #000000   0.5
2     2  6 #1C0000   0.7
3     3  2 #390000   0.4
4     4  6 #550000   0.2
5     5  2 #710000   0.3
6     6  6 #8E0000   0.8
7     7  2 #AA0000   0.9
8     8  6 #C60000   0.6
9     9  2 #E30000     1
10   10  6 #FF0000   0.1
```

Gives this graph:[image: Resulting graph]

You can see that the colors in the data frame are not interpreted. I was expecting `scale_color_identity()` to achieve this as indicated on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43129280/color-points-with-the-color-as-a-column-in-ggplot2) and from the function's help. If I put `edge_color` outside the aesthetics

`geom_edge_arc0(aes(edge_width=width), edge_color=test.df$col)`

I get an error requesting me to provide data of length 36. If I test what these 36 values do with

`geom_edge_arc0(aes(edge_width=width), edge_color = rep(test.df$col, each=4)[-1:-4])`

I see the colors of the df interpreted, but wrongly assigned (the color order matches the order of the line thinkness).
[image]
That's doubly confusing and so this brings me to these three questions:

a) How do I achieve what I want?

b) Why does color outside `aes()` request 36 values? It's not even a multiple of the 10 lines and rather 4*lines -4. `geom_edge_arc` and `geom_edge_arc2` even request 900 values. Where can I look up what all these values are asking for?

c) Why does the order of colors not match the data frame if I define the color outside `aes()`?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to issue a)

I have to explicitely use `scale_edge_color_identity()` instead of `scale_color_identity()` to interpret the dataframe colors!